# Multiple Realsense Point Cloud Fusion based on Extrinsics

Tags: c++, opencv, point-clouds, realsense

how to merge point cloud files in real-time? Briefly about my application:
I have two Realsense D435 with which I record one point cloud each. I want to align these point clouds using the extrinsic camera parameters and thus convert them into a point cloud. Then I want to render a 2D image from this point cloud and process it in OpenCV.

Thanks a lot for your tips!

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d9b/classcv_1_1ppf__match__3d_1_1ICP.html

Comment: with extrinsics you can just merge the global points (R*p + T). If you need better alignment of merging, use ICP. If you need a better model representation use truncated signed distance function, which is great for renderinf, too.

Comment: thanks for your two tips. i will take a closer look at the truncated signed distance function. @Micka

Comment: @Miki 
at the moment i do not understand the class , but i try to understand it.

Comment: for truncated signed distance function have a look at the "kinect fusion" paper. There it is described quite well.

Comment: I have now merged the RGB-D point clouds based on their extrinsic parameters. The display is in OpenGL. Unfortunately I have not yet progressed with rendering the 2D representation. Strictly speaking, OpenGL creates a 2D image on my monitor from the 3D scene. In what way could truncated signed distance function help me now? I also didn't find anything about whether the rendered image could be accessed from OpenGL. Thanks for your help!